# Disable Spring Data Redis TLS verification in application.yml

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

We're using spring-data-redis and Azure Cache for Redis. When debugging locally, the only way to connect is to use TLS, but disable the peer verification - as I understand it, Azure does something weird with the certificates which makes them fail verification (https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/1454).

It's simple enough to disable this using the builder for RedisConnectionFactory and setting `configurationBuilder.useSsl().disablePeerVerification();`, but we've moved away from using a separate config file and moved all the config to application.yml. Is there an equivalent option I could add to the redis block in this file to turn off peer verification? I've been through the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use `ConditionalOnProperty` and `LettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer`

For instance:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = {"spring.redis.ssl"},
        havingValue = "true"
)
public LettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer lettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer(){
    return (clientConfigurationBuilder) ->{
        clientConfigurationBuilder.useSsl().disablePeerVerification();
    };
}
```